# How do I blacklist QtCreator in AltTab on a Mac?

Tags: macos, qt, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator

I am using [AltTab](https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/) on a Mac for switching between apps but Alt-Tab is the shortcut in QtCreator for switching between files, and AltTab has stolen this key combination. Therefore I need to blacklist QtCreator in AltTab.

What is the name of QtCreator in the `com.acme.myapp` notation? It seems that AltTab requires this, because simply putting `QtCreator` has not worked.

Comment: `com.qt.QtCreator` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

for switching between tabs in the OS you can use the Alt+Tab

in qt creator you can switch between files using control + tab, but you can disable the shortcut

select **Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard.**
and there find the "Go To prev history"
and remove the shortcut...

after that the problem is gone.-

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is on a Mac.
In QtCreator the shortcut for GotoPreviousInHistory is Opt+Tab (i.e. Alt-Tab on a non-mac keyboard).
I want the shortcut to work in QtCreator. I want to stop the AltTab application from stealing that combination of key presses from QtCreator.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this

```
osascript -e 'id of app "QtCreator"'
```